# Texmaker system font size

Tags: fonts, texmaker

How can I change the system font size in Texmaker? I do not now, how it became so large. In options I found only font size for editor part.

[image: texmaker screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be two settings that are affecting your view the overall interface has been scaled UP and the internal edit font has been scaled down.

This is often caused on high resolution screens by QT platform increasing User Interface  scaling either in environment of Texmaker or by another QT application.

When starting Texmaker 5 (not Texmaker 4) it is possible for the user to override any automatic or environmental settings by adding a command switch.

So my start-up for example is "whatever\texmaker.exe" -dpiscale 1.0

For the internal editor window by way of illustration I have set my font large
[image]